# How to understand and explain phrase "to line city coffers"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was watching [this](http://lingualeo.com/ru/jungle/how-were-priming-some-kids-for-college-and-others-for-prison-390994#/page/1) video and faced a problem: I don't know how to understand the phrase "to line city coffers"? I've faced that phrase at the end of the following long sentence:

"The problem's actually a bit worse than this 'cause we're not just sending 
poor kids to prison, we're saddling poor kids with court fees, with probation and parole restrictions, with low-level warrants, we're asking them to live in halfway houses and on house arrest, and we're asking them to negotiate a police force that is entering poor communities of color, not for the purposes of promoting public safety, but to make arrest counts, to line city coffers."

Comment: [Line your (own)/somebody’s pockets](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/line_2), [coffers](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/coffer#coffer__5).

Comment: @user2684291 thanks, I was not able to find it because in my situation coffers are instead of pockets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [coffer is a box for money](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coffer). Lining refers to (I think) to the "[inner layer of fabric, fur, or other material inserted into clothing, hats, luggage, curtains, handbags and similar items](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lining_(sewing))."

This is a metaphor that says the city is imposing fees on the people not to enforce the law, but to make money (i.e. figuratively "make an inner layer of dollar bills for their money strongbox").

Comment: One of the meanings of the verb **to line** is "to fill". We have an expression for *bribery* -- "to line someone's palm with silver"

Comment: @TRomano your comment is as useful as the answer